# How can I use between clause to filter out 2 different datetime fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, between

I need to implement a hall booking system and there is a requirement to get the free halls based on booked `FromDateTime` to `ToDateTime`

Order Table

```
HallID       FromDateTime            ToDateTime
1        2018-01-01 03:00:00    2018-01-01 05:00:00
2        2018-01-01 06:30:00    2018-01-01 12:00:00
3        2018-01-01 13:00:00    2018-01-01 15:15:00
```

The user should be able to input the `FromDateTime` to `ToDateTime` to check whether there is a record in the Order table. If exists then hall is not available for booking.

Test scenarios: Inputs

```
    FromDateTime           ToDateTime           Result
2018-01-01 03:00:00    2018-01-01 05:00:00 : Hall not available
2018-01-01 08:45:00    2018-01-01 10:30:00 : Hall not available (This time is between Hall ID 2s booking time)
2018-01-01 15:30:00    2018-01-01 18:00:00 : Hall available
```

Question

Is it possible to use between clause within `FromDateTime` and `ToDateTime` in this scenario to solve this problem?
I was unable to find a way to use between so I used the below method. But its cost is very high.

```
-- Selecting all the records related to perticular product(hall) in to a temp table.

DECLARE @TempOrderDateTime TABLE (FromDateTime DATETIME,ToDateTime DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @TempOrderDateTime
SELECT FromDateTime,ToDateTime
FROM [Order].[Order]
WHERE ProductID = 7
```

Splitting each and every record into 1-hour potions and storing inside temp table. This creates another issue.

The issue is if I use 1-hour segments algorithm will not be able to deal with records which are having minutes in FromDateTime or ToDateTime

```
DECLARE @ProdTimes TABLE (Dates DATETIME)
DECLARE @PRowCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TempOrderDateTime)
WHILE(@PRowCount>0)
BEGIN
DECLARE @TopFromDateTime DATETIME = (SELECT TOP(1)FromDateTime FROM 
@TempOrderDateTime)
DECLARE @TopToDateTime DATETIME = (SELECT TOP(1)ToDateTime FROM @TempOrderDateTime)    
;WITH Dates_CTE 
     AS (SELECT @TopFromDateTime AS Dates
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 1, Dates)
         FROM   Dates_CTE
         WHERE  Dates < @TopToDateTime)
INSERT INTO @ProdTimes
SELECT Dates
FROM   Dates_CTE AS t
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
         DELETE TOP(1) FROM @TempOrderDateTime 
         SET @PRowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TempOrderDateTime)
END
```

Here I am givingFromDateTime and ToDateTime as inputs in order to check the availability.

```
DECLARE @FromDateTime DATETIME  = '2018-06-01 12:00:00.000'
DECLARE @ToDateTime DATETIME = '2018-06-01 14:00:00.000'
DECLARE @PTimes TABLE (Dates DateTime)  

;WITH Dates_CTE
     AS (SELECT @FromDateTime AS Dates
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 1, Dates)
         FROM   Dates_CTE
         WHERE  Dates < @ToDateTime)
INSERT INTO @PTimes
SELECT *
FROM   Dates_CTE AS t
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

DELETE FROM @PTimes WHERE Dates = @FromDateTime OR Dates = @ToDateTime
```

Finally doing the below operation to match the tables. If no records found, the hall is available for booking.

```
SELECT * FROM @PTimes p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @ProdTimes pt WHERE p.Dates = pt.Dates)
```

My approach is currently applicable. But the major drawback is

- If the order table records contain an entry with Minutes, the algorithm will not work. Because it only filters out 1-hour potions.
- Cost is very high.

Please suggest me a proper way to handle this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `between` operator for datetime formats of course. this should be a correct syntax: `WHERE Dates BETWEEN @FromDateTime AND @ToDateTime`

Comment: What about the result for the cases with `FromDateTime: 2018-01-01 15:00:00   ToDateTime: 2018-01-01 18:00:00` or `FromDateTime: 2018-01-01 02:30:00   ToDateTime: 2018-01-01 04:00:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `between`.  The logic is:

```
select h.*
from halls h
where not exists (select 1
                  from orders o
                  where o.hallid = h.hallid and
                        o.FromDateTime < @ToDateTime and
                        o.ToDateTime > @FromDateTime
                 );
```

I'm pretty sure this is the simplest solution to your problem.  Note that the definition of overlap does not involve `between` at all.  Two periods overlap if one begins before the second end and ends after the second begins.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i got the point, but if not feel free to comment this.

Lets say the user is going to submit a request at `2018-01-01-04:30:00`

DATES Table:

```
   FromDateTime           ToDateTime           Result
2018-01-01 03:00:00    2018-01-01 05:00:00 : Hall not available
2018-01-01 08:45:00    2018-01-01 10:30:00 : Hall not available (This time is between Hall ID 2s booking time)
2018-01-01 15:30:00    2018-01-01 18:00:00 : Hall available
```

Your check should be something like:

```
DECLARE @UserDateRequest DATETIME = '2018-01-01-04:30:00'
SELECT @UserDateRequest,
       Result
FROM DATES
WHERE @UserDateRequests BETWEEN @FromDateTime AND @ToDateTime
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on your answer. Ill get back to you